# Why is my MAUI Custom Control not showing the binded data?

Tags: c#, maui

Component:

`back-end`:

```cs
namespace OneCampus.Components;

public partial class TimeEntryCard : ContentView
{
    // does this need to be "public static??"
    public static readonly BindableProperty DayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DayProperty), typeof(string), typeof(TimeEntryCard), string.Empty);

    public string Day
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(DayProperty);
        set => SetValue(DayProperty, value);
    }

    public TimeEntryCard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

`front-end`:

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OneCampus.Components.TimeEntryCard">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue" 
               HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Day}" />
                <VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding InTime}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding OutTime}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding TotalTime}" />
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</ContentView>
```

---

Usage:

```xaml
<customctrl:TimeEntryCard Day="Monday"/>
```

`Result`:
[image: custom control actual]

---

If I do not use `Binding`:

```xaml
<Label Text="Day" />
```

Output:

[image: actual look]

---

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two usage errors in your code.

1.from document [Create a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-property), we know that :

> Important
>
> The naming convention for bindable properties is that the bindable
> property identifier must match the property name specified in the
> Create method, with "Property" appended to it.

so, you can try to change the following code:

```
//public static readonly BindableProperty DayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(DayProperty), typeof(string), typeof(TimeEntryCard), string.Empty);
```

To

```
public static readonly BindableProperty DayProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Day), typeof(string), typeof(TimeEntryCard), string.Empty);
```

2.in your `TimeEntryCard.xaml`, try to use [Binding Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-path).

Please refer to the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiContentViewApp.TimeEntryCard"
              x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue" 
               HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <HorizontalStackLayout Spacing="10">
                <Label     TextColor="Yellow" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=Day}"/>
                <!--<VerticalStackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding InTime}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding OutTime}" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding TotalTime}" />-->
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And the text could display normally on my side after I used the following code on `MyPage.xaml`

```
 <mauiapp:TimeEntryCard Day="Monday"></mauiapp:TimeEntryCard>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can you please try to elaborate what exactly was wrong with using just plain old `Binding`? I'd followed the tutorial given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/contentview?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 1):

Your Binding is wrong, when you need to bind your `Property` from code-behind into your View Xaml you need to provide context because it by default sets the BindingContext to your ViewModel when you are using a custom control in a View.

To understand what I mean, override the OnBindingContextChanged method in your custom control and check its parameter.

Anyway, coming back to your control, add the follow changes to it and it should work, Give your ContentView a name:

```
 <ContentView 
  x:Name="this"
  ...>
```

Then in your Label refer to the CurrentPage:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding Day, Source={x:Reference this}}" />
```

If you want to check out how a lot of custom controls are created you can check out this Maui library I created [FreakyControls](https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls/tree/master/MAUI.FreakyControls/MAUI.FreakyControls/Shared). It's essentially a UIKit with controls that have additional properties to make it easier to code with Maui.